# selection of transformer for flyback converter

Tags: transformer, flyback

I am designing a flyback converter. Now, necessary parameters are as stated -

Vin(voltage to primary) = 17-32V,
Vout(voltage to secondary) = 12V,
Iout = 3Amps.

Now, based on the above requirements, I calculated the following parameters for the flyback transformer -

Pout = 36W,

Assuming 80% efficiency, Pin = 45W.

Iaverage = Pin/Vin = 45/17 = 2.647Amps.

Iavg 0 Ipk*(Duty cycle)*0.5. Where D - 50% duty cycle.
Hence-forth , Ipk(peak current) = 2.647/(0.5*0.5) = 10Amps.

So, V = L*dI/dT => L = 17*(ton)/dI = 8.02uH. The inductance o0f the primary coil.

Nr(ratios) = Nsec/Npri = 0.70588 => Nsec = (Npri)*(0.705).
Now, with the above values, I tried selecting a flyback transformer.

I am looking at the transformer PA3856.006NL.

[image: Flyback transformer]

Now, is my approach correct ? If so, in the transformer I have show, where is the turns ratio specified ?

Also, what is the actual advantage of have a dual output in the secondary ? Does it have to do with the current on the output and its effects on the transformer saturation current.

Comment: Um, PA3856.006NL is a transformer for a forward application (note "Forward Transformer" beneath the diagram and note the phase dots). They're not interchangeable.

Comment: Yes, my bad, its written forward transformer. But, the comment about dots dont stand as the same then will apply to the flyback ones shown in the same datasheet - http://productfinder.pulseeng.com/products/datasheets/P719.pdf

Also, are flyback and forward transformers interchangeable in applications ?

Comment: Absolutely NOT interchangeable! The construction and energy-handling requirements are totally different between forward and flyback transformers.

Comment: @AdamLawrence. Thank you for the advice. In the same family, there is a PA3855.006NL transformer(flyback). Now,, my calculated Nsecondary is 0.705w.r.t primary. or, Npri = 1.4184. What if I select a primary of larger turns, say 2.5 turns ?

Comment: Also, what does 0.47 stand for in the primary ? Is it saturation current or turns in the coil ?

Answer (score 1):

The PA3856.006NL can be used as a flyback transformer. Note 2 in the data sheet states this: -

> 2. For flyback topology applications, it is necessary to ensure that the transformer will not saturate in the application. The peak flux
>      density (Bpk) should remain below 2700Gauss. To calculate the peak
>      flux density use the following formula: Bpk (Gauss) = K1_Factor *
>      Ipk(A)

Given that the peak primary current is calculated as 10 amps on the lowest input volts, Bpk (Gauss) = 41.7 x 10 = 417 gauss and this is well short of 2700 gauss.

> Now, is my approach correct ?

Your approach does seem correct but you forgot to mention operating frequency however, i reasoned that the on time is 4.72 us if that helps.

> where is the turns ratio specified ?

The turns ratio is 0.47:1 as shown by the little numbers on the picture of the transformer in your question.

> Also, what is the actual advantage of have a dual output in the
>   secondary ? Does it have to do with the current on the output and its
>   effects on the transformer saturation current.

Dual output means you can wire them in series or in parallel. Saturation of the core is caused by primary current reaching too high a value.

Comment: *Saturation of the core is caused by primary current reaching too high a value.* No? Saturation of the core is caused by having the core eat up too much voltage-time before it is magnetized in the other direction. You have to limit this voltage-time integral over a half-period.

Comment: @Janka the two are totally inter-related. You can convert volt seconds into ampere turns and get the same answer. Do the math. Magnetic flux is caused by current ([biot savart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biot%E2%80%93Savart_law) law) but can also be regarded as volt-seconds. No, I'm not wrong. Also look up core BH curves and see what causes saturation (ampere turns per metre = H)

Comment: @Janka consider this: V = L.di/dt therefore V.dt = L.di or, if we reduced L to being proportional to turns squared you find that volt seconds per turn = ampere turns.

Comment: This is a never-ending discussion, seen that at another place. The simplest way to calculate it is integrating the voltage curve over time during a half wave. That value has to be smaller than the Webers from the particular core datasheet (or Gauss/Tesla value times the cross section of the core.)

Comment: Of course so why were you questioning my use of amps in the primary if you've seen this before (at another place). Sorry for asking but I get it in the head once or twice a year from @Neil and he just doesn't seem to comprehend that the two are the same and if I choose to use ampere turns or amps in describing a magnetic field then who can argue (or more importantly why should anyone argue?).

Comment: @Janka and NO, it's not the simplest way when looking at ferrite data sheets for flyback converters and that is what this question is about and that is partially what I do for a living.

Comment: I always see it as Vt=NAB=IL and you can simply pick your poison. For voltage source, say flyback primary I find Vt to be far simpler. An output inductor on the other hand, IL.